# Universal Connection Pool already exists error (Oracle UCP)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ucp

I am trying to create a UniversalConnectonPool using the code below:

```
// Read and process properties
PoolDataSource poolDataSource = createUniversalConnectionPool();
    
universalConnectionPoolManager = UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager();
    
universalConnectionPoolManager.createConnectionPool((UniversalConnectionPoolAdapter) poolDataSource);
    
universalConnectionPoolManager.startConnectionPool(getSchema());

.
.
.
.

UniversalConnectionPool universalConnectionPool = universalConnectionPoolManager.getConnectionPool(getSchema());
UniversalPooledConnection universalPooledConnection = universalConnectionPool.borrowConnection(universalConnectionPool.getConnectionRetrievalInfo());

connection = (Connection) universalPooledConnection.getPhysicalConnection();
```

But the third line `universalConnectionPoolManager.createConnectionPool((UniversalConnectionPoolAdapter) poolDataSource);` throws the exception:

```
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Universal Connection Pool already exists in the Universal Connection Pool Manager. Universal Connection Pool cannot be added to the Universal Connection Pool Manager
        at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:421)
        at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:389)
        at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:403)
        at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerBase.setConnectionPool(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerBase.java:599)
        at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerBase.createConnectionPool(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerBase.java:559)
        ... 30 more
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am new to using Connection Pools, so still learning the ins-and-outs of it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one pools with same name.
In your case it seems you already have an existing pool with same name.
You can refer UCP code sample [here](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/BasicSamples/UCPSample.java).

Also, to borrow and return connection to pool you can use below standard APIs.
Please note that calling poolDataSource.getConnection() internally creates and starts the pool if it was not already started.

```
// borrows a connection
Connection conn = poolDataSource.getConnection();
// return connection to pool
conn.close();
```

Comment: The sample code in the link is already written in `createUniversalConnectionPool()`. And since this is at server startup, I doubt that there is any other data source created.

Comment: // Read and process properties
PoolDataSource poolDataSource = createUniversalConnectionPool();This line is enough to configure the pool. After this you can simply call 
poolDataSource.getConnection() to borrow a connection from pool. Calling getConnection() will internally create and start the pool, no need to do it explicitly.